# appendTo with a moving effect

Tags: jquery

I want to make appendTo moving with a smooth effect .. i mean attach a transition moving effect to appendTo .. here is my code ..

```
<div class="carousel">

  <!--10 Elements-->    

    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>
    <div class="carouselElement"><div>

<div>
```

Jquery:

```
        //Carousel Script .. 
   var nextbtnNclicks =1;
    var currentarticle = nextbtnNclicks -1;


    $(".nextabs i").on("click",function(){
        if(nextbtnNclicks>10) {
            nextbtnNclicks =1;
        }

        $(".carouselElement").eq(currentarticle).appendTo(".carousel",200);
        nextbtnNclicks++
    });
```

Comment: What kind of transition?

Comment: moving to right or left .. previous and next

Comment: Devil's advocate.  There are a ton of carousel implementations on the web.  Why are you trying to roll your own?